# Android IME backspace (delete) act like hardware back key

Tags: android, events

If I press softkeyboard BACKSPACE key my app behave like I pressed hardware BACK key. I noticed that my onKeyDown() is called when I press softkeyboard delete key. That happens only on android 4.0. On Android 2.2. everything works good.

Does anyone have idea how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find how to avoid the call of the `onKeyDown()` method when user press the delete button on soft keyboard but I manage to to find solution which works good.
I changed the `onKeyDown()` method in a way that she do nothing if keyCode is `KEYCODE_DEL`

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
        return true;
    }
    else{
    Boolean result = overlayManager.onKeyDown();
    if (result) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    }
}
```